# SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated in eclipse but not intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, keystore

So I have some code that interfaces with an external rest service. I imported its SSL cert into my java keystore and my unit tests work fine...while I'm using intellij. Other members on my team use eclipse and even though the cert is in their keystore they get the dreaded **peer not authenticated** exception.

Even on my computer with all the certs in the chain in my keystore it works in intellij but not eclipse.

My great Google skills have failed me on this one. Help me, StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

*eclipse stack trace*

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:126)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:437)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
```